# Which Linux capability to use to properly run "sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.route_localnet=1" in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, networking, openvpn, sysctl, linux-capabilities

I'm using an OpenVPN server in a Docker container for multiple client connections.
This container is located in a **specific Docker network** in which I have a web server as client target.

I want to publish the host name of my web server to clients so that they won't need to know its IP address in order to reach it.
To do so, **I want to open the Docker's native DNS server to the OpenVPN clients** and push to them the OpenVPN's IP as DNS server.

However, the Docker DNS server resides in the OpenVPN container, listening on 127.0.0.11 (with *iptables* internal redirections but that's another story).

Thus, in the OpenVPN server container, I need to add an *iptables* rule in order to forward a DNS request coming from the external OpenVPN IP to the internal 127.0.0.11 one.

But such an internal forward requires me to execute the following command:

```sh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.tun0.route_localnet=1
```

Using the only *NET_ADMIN* capability when running `docker run` (`--cap-add=NET_ADMIN`), I get the following error message:

```
sysctl: error setting key 'net.ipv4.conf.tun0.route_localnet': Read-only file system
```

However, this perfectly works using the `--privileged` flag, **but the one is too permissive**.

Is there any Linux capability that can do the trick **without using the `--privileged` flag**?
I couldn't find the answer in the [Linux capabilities manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, using the `--sysctl`'s `docker run` option

Solution in *docker-compose.yml*:

```yaml
sysctls:
    - net.ipv4.conf.tun0.route_localnet=1    # Doesn't work as tun0 doesn't 
                                             # exist yet at container start time
    - net.ipv4.conf.default.route_localnet=1 # Workaround.
```